# React Typescript default type for HTML table properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm trying to put default value to align props which should append itself to the HTML's td but i kept getting this ts error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"left" | "center" | "right" | "justify" | "char"
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from 'react'

export interface TableColumnProps {
  children: ReactNode,
  align?: string,
  className?: string,
  width?: string,
  onClick: () => void,
}

const TableColumn = ({ children, align = 'left', className, onClick, width }: TableColumnProps) => (
  <td className={className} align={align} width={width} onClick={onClick}>
    {children}
  </td>
)

export default TableColumn
```

Comment: Possibly because 'align' is not supported in HTML5.

Comment: Have you tried to set your interface to `... align: "left" | "center" | "right" | "justify" | "char"`? It seems to expect these concrete values, and if you set the type to "string", any other string value should cause type mismatch anyway.

Comment: Thanks @kbo, I thought it'll be something like importing HTML type attributes thing but your version seems to work. Cheers!